# Recommendation for SQL documentation tools?

Tags: sql, documentation-generation

Can anybody recommend me an SQL documentation tool that I can:

1. document SQL Server databases;
2. add comments to generate descriptions of tables, views, stored procedures, functions and their columns, fields and parameters.

Thank you!

Comment: SQLRaptor does all the basic stuff...http://www.miqui.it/sqlraptor.htm

Comment: Try **[Dataedo](http://dataedo.com)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically two valid contenders, for SQL Server, in my opinion:

- [Red-Gate SQL Doc](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/)
  See their [online AdventureWorks sample](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/browse-sql-doc/main) to get an impression of what those docs look like
- [ApexSQL ApexSQL Doc](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_doc.aspx)

Comment: I suggest a more recent and less expensive tool than the excellent SQL Doc be added to this contenders list, which is [Database Note Taker](http://databasenotetaker.com) which is a great platform to add comments to the database objects and attributes which need it.

Comment: Hi @ActionDan. In the documentation they say that Database note taker can work with other database other than sql server or mysql. I'm interested in working with Oracle but I'm not able to create the connection due to the driver. Have you any experience with it?

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli the architecture allows us to add others (via ODBC) and we were asked for Oracle before but we don't use it ourselves so need help to add it. It would be via ODBC using an Oracle driver and we need to know the sql to list tables, columns etc and assistance to test that. If you are willing to help email through to the email address mentioned on the web site

Answer (score 1):

Sybase Power Designer, Oracle SQL developer data modeler (it looks strange but it could create data model for mssql)